# Parsing out $ factor to numeric in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataframe with a variable that is a factor containing $ signs. So the column is something like Revenue: $450, $550, $650 ..etc. I'd like to strip the $ and transform factor to numeric.

I tried parsing using methods found on stackoverflow but they return and error message. Are $ special symbols?

Here's what I've tried:

```
str_replace(df$Revenue, "$", "") #error message
as.numeric(gsub("$", "", df$Revenue) #Similar error message
```

These work to remove symbols like "%" but for some reason not replicable with "$". Any reason why?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
myvec <- c("$450", "$550", "$650")
as.numeric(gsub('\\$', '', myvec))
#[1] 450 550 650
```

Or as an alternative:

```
as.numeric(gsub('$', '', myvec, fixed = TRUE))
#[1] 450 550 650
```

You would need to escape `$` to make it work with regex (because `$` is a special character) or set `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't realize $ was a special character. What else are special characters in R?

Comment: They are special character in regex not R. `. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?` these are the main ones. You can read more about it if you type `?regex` on your console.

Comment: I have found this to be a great summary: http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html

Comment: This is exactly what we use in a production system which collects financial data. :)